# python 2.7 polar function

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run the below program , shows an error. Please help me to rectify.

```
from pylab import *
polar(pi/2,5,'g*')
show()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 236, in resize
    self.show()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 239, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 401, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 884, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 1983, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1040, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: seeing that you didn't say what are you trying to archive is a bit difficult understand for what you need it, in any case have a look at this: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to `import math` and then use `polar(math.pi/2,5,'g*')`
you can also `import numpy as np` and use `np.pi`